# Bind Authoritive cluster upgrade order

Tags: bind, process, shutdown

We are running BIND 9.16.6 Red Hat v7.7.
I am looking for some tips on the order of the upgrade and what command to run in order to shut down each node gracefully.
We have a separate hidden master and 2 slaves.

This is in response to CVE-2023-2828.

Comment: If you're applying this upgrade now you're two months late to the party.

Comment: I have always been fashionably late thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for any special ordering.
Just `yum upgrade` to install updates and `shutdown -r now` to restart the machine.